# Why is responseText outputting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

CodeIgniter 3.0

Form uses button as the submit event:
`<button type="button" name="submit">SEARCH</button>`

Here is the very simple javascript I have so far, and I don't see why it should be outputting the form page in an alert box:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("button[name='submit']").click(function(){
        //
    });        
});
```

Produces an alert box with readystate, statustext, and responsetext:

```
200 , OK, <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
(...and the entire html output of the form page goes here...)
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why my js should output anything if I haven't told it to.

Comment: what is the form action attribute value ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, why would the action value matter? I don't think it is relevant to the question. Please explain why it would be? I haven't made a submit action yet.

Comment: I didn't understand the question initially. Now I do. Action attribute is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I was calling another javascript in my head, which had an identical `$(document).ready(function` script section. Even the `<button name='submit']` was the same, so my javascript much have got confused and just threw up the status codes and responsetext.